# Error when changing ion-radio value from M to F

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm getting a strange error when trying to change the radio button value and posting it in my soap writeData. For example I'm trying to change the gender from M to F, I console.log it and the value in result of the change is like this: rb-1-0

This is my code:

```
<div radio-group formControlName="gender" style="margin-top:-3%;margin-left:23%" [(ngModel)]="customer.SESSO">
        <ion-radio color="dark" [value]="F" [checked]="customer.SESSO == 'f'"></ion-radio>
        <span>
          <strong style="position: absolute;margin-top: -1%; margin-left: 2%;font-size:16px">F</strong>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div radio-group formControlName="gender" style="margin-left: 47%;margin-top: -10%" [(ngModel)]="customer.SESSO"
      class="radio-privacy in-middle">
        <ion-radio color="dark" [value]="M" [checked]="customer.SESSO == 'm'"></ion-radio>
        <span>
          <strong style="position: absolute;margin-top: -1%;margin-left: 4%;font-size:16px">M</strong>
        </span>
      </div>
```

How can I solve passing this wrong value?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

please add two item in one group e.g.

```
<ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="gender">

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Male</ion-label>
    <ion-radio value="M"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Female</ion-label>
    <ion-radio value="F"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

now declare variable on ts file `gender:any;` when you on button please `console.log(gender)` you will get the M of F value

Comment: My NgModel is like this: [(ngModel)]="customer.SESSO" . Than your code is not working, I need 2 radio button like this: https://imgur.com/a/zzbvi1b